# My React site is load fine in pc's browsers but not in mobile browser why?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, react-redux, react-router

I have created a site using React + Node.js .
Site works fine in pc's browser and do all functions. but in mobile site can't load landing page only show white (blank) page. I could not understand what is the issue behind.
The Site url is:
[click here to visit site](https://speedsy.com.speedsyracewear.com/)

Comment: Nope, the site doesn't load for me in my desktop Chrome either. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined at 2.9062e09a.chunk.js:1".

Comment: showing blank white screen my pc's browser...i am using mozilla firefox

Comment: Oh i know why (maybe) you are requiring react dev tools, it should only be added in dev environment and not when code is pushed in production maybe something like https://github.com/adeelibr/react-starter-kit/blob/master/src/store/index.js

Comment: Thank you all. I have found the problem I forget to remove redux devTools extension for products environment. Now its fine .